# How can I write an Excel macro to select a group of cells?

Tags: vba, excel, select, range

I'm looking for a macro which can be run to select a consistent range of cells so that I can easily copy them to another spreadsheet. The range would be F3:BJ3.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
Public Sub selectCells()
    Range("F3:BJ3").Select
End Sub
```

**edit:** for that matter, you can use the following to actually perform the 'copy' command for you as well:

```
Public Sub selectCellsAndCopy()
    Range("F3:BJ3").Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this one it is working fine.

```
Sub On_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E1").Select
End Sub
```